# Spring Boot динамические Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, entity

В SpringBoot появилась необходимость сделать `Entity` у которого будут динамические поля. Суть задачи в том, что администратор имеет право расширять таблицу `Entity` добавляя туда поля через `ALTER TABLE` (не руками конечно же, он кидает запрос в приложение, оно уже делает `ALTER`) и прикол в том, что мне бы хотелось чтобы мой `Entity` при запросах выборки, добавления и обновления мог работать с этими полями "на лету" без переписывания кода приложения, хотя бы в виде какой-то `Map`, понятное дело, что в `Class` вряд ли получится добавлять поля, но хотя бы `Map<String, Object>` (где String - имя поля, Object - его значение) было бы неплохо как-то получать, реально ли это или придется ручками эту механику прописывать отказываясь от использования `Entity`?

Хотелось бы иметь что-то в духе:.

```
    Map<String, Object> getEntity(Long id);
    void updateEntities(Map<Long, Map<String, Object>>
    void save(Map<String, Object>) //Map<String, Object> содержит id в т.ч.
```

или

```
    Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> getAllEntities();
```

Ну и подобные им запросы с `WHERE` и т.д.

Comment: делать `ALTER TABLE`  в процессе работы плохая практика. Заведите таблицу связанную с `Entity` и получите ту же Map. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persisting-maps

Comment: В том-то и прикол, что происходить эта операция будет не слишком часто (по идее) и оптимальнее иметь это поле прям в модели пользователя, а не для каждого Entity иметь связь OneToMany с ещё какой-то таблицей - при каждой выдаче больше времени тратить придется

Comment: Не важно насколько часто будет создавать колонки. Это в принципе противоречит нормальной жизни БД и работы с ней. Кешуриуйте результат. Тут за Вас все сделает Хибер, а там придется писать все самому и без хибера - jdbc или же jdtc template. Нужен ли Вам такой геморой?